# Efficient method for appending property to a legend

Tags: javascript

I am working on an application - that will loop through data - and I want to append a property to an existing legend - without using two for loops.

```
let listRegions = [{
    "label" : "A",
    "value" : "SIEA"
},{
    "label" : "E",
    "value" : "SIEE"
},{
    "label" : "JA",
    "value" : "SIEJA-JAPAN"
},{
    "label" : "AS",
    "value" : "SIEJA-ASIA"
}];
```

essentially - as it comes across a row of data -- I want to clone this array - and add isIncluded property to each of the values -- but set the isIncluded to true if its found

```
let newList= [{
    "label" : "A",
    "value" : "SIEA",
    "isIncluded": true
},{
    "label" : "E",
    "value" : "SIEE",
    "isIncluded": false
},{
    "label" : "JA",
    "value" : "SIEJA-JAPAN",
    "isIncluded": false
},{
    "label" : "AS",
    "value" : "SIEJA-ASIA",
    "isIncluded": false
}];
```

---

something like this
https://jsfiddle.net/eb2zx70m/1/

```
let listRegions = [{
  "label": "A",
  "value": "SIEA"
}, {
  "label": "E",
  "value": "SIEE"
}, {
  "label": "JA",
  "value": "SIEJA-JAPAN"
}, {
  "label": "AS",
  "value": "SIEJA-ASIA"
}];

console.log("listRegions", listRegions);

var regions = ["SIEJA-ASIA", "SIEE"];
console.log("regions", regions);

for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {


  let legendRegions = [];
  listRegions.forEach(function(e) {
    console.log("regions[i]", regions[i]);
    console.log("e.value", e.value);

    if (e.value === regions[i]) {
      console.log("e.value", e.value);
      e.enabled = true;
    } else {
      e.enabled = false;
    }
    legendRegions.push(e);

    console.log("newList", legendRegions);
  });



};
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use two for loops? You are iterating through two collections, so it is unavoidable that you need two for loops. Well, you can avoid the loops, using functions like `forEach` but still you use them under the hood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
// N list regions
const listRegions = [{
  "label": "A",
  "value": "SIEA"
}, {
  "label": "E",
  "value": "SIEE"
}, {
  "label": "JA",
  "value": "SIEJA-JAPAN"
}, {
  "label": "AS",
  "value": "SIEJA-ASIA"
}];

// K regions
const regions = ["SIEJA-ASIA", "SIEE"];
// complexity O(K)
const includedRegions = regions.reduce((res, region) => ({
  ...res,
  [region]: true
}), {});

// complexity O(N)
const newList = listRegions.map(region => ({
  ...region,
  isIncluded: !!includedRegions[region.value]
}));

// total complexity O(N + K)
console.log(newList);
```

Here is the same solution but without declaring additional `regionsIncluded` map. This map is passed as a `thisArg` to [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters) function:

```js
// N list regions
const listRegions = [{
  "label": "A",
  "value": "SIEA"
}, {
  "label": "E",
  "value": "SIEE"
}, {
  "label": "JA",
  "value": "SIEJA-JAPAN"
}, {
  "label": "AS",
  "value": "SIEJA-ASIA"
}];

// K regions
const regions = ["SIEJA-ASIA", "SIEE"];

// complexity O(N) and O(K) for thisArg value
const newList = listRegions.map(region => ({
  ...region,
  isIncluded: Boolean(this[region.value])
}), regions.reduce((res, region) => ({
  ...res,
  [region]: true
}), {}));

// total complexity O(N + K)
console.log(newList);
```

Comment: my data is more like this -- includedRegions = "SIEJA-JAPAN"

Comment: I updated my answer with code which builds `includedRegions` map in O(K) complexity, where K is the size of `regions` array. Thus, total complexity of this solution is `O(K + N)` which is more efficient than accepted solution where complexity is O(K x N). See my comments in updated answer

Comment: What a bad argument since you have to do an additional `reduce` to even be able to apply your solution. The performance benefits of having K + N instead of K * N is absolutely irrelevant for the usecase shown, but requires to create an additional data structure, and from a maintenance point of view, higher code complexity. Plus a double negation to coerce `undefined` into a boolean.

Comment: I updated my answer with no additional variable, thanks for pointing out. 1 x O(K) `Array.reduce()` is used instead of N x O(K) `Array.includes()`, thus, making is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `regions.includes(region)` inside a single `map()` call:

```js
const listRegions = [{"label": "A", "value": "SIEA"}, {"label": "E", "value": "SIEE"}, {"label": "JA", "value": "SIEJA-JAPAN"}, {"label": "AS", "value": "SIEJA-ASIA"}];
const regions = ["SIEJA-ASIA", "SIEE"];
const legendRegions = listRegions.map(region => (
  { 
    ...region, 
    isIncluded: regions.includes(region.value)
  })
);
console.log(legendRegions);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59936414/d3js-error-in-rendering-a-legend-key-duplicated-render  -- this follows on

Answer (score 0):

```
listRegions.forEach(el => {
    if (condition) {
        el.isIncluded = true
    } else {
        el.isIncluded = false
    }
  console.log(el)
})
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because he wants to clone the array for every value in a collection of values.

Comment: this doesn't work - as the elements for listRegions is the same?

Answer (score -1):

The code samples you have are working --- but when I bolt it into my exact example I am still left with a flaw.

regions is an array of ALL my rows - ["SIEJA-JAPAN", "SIEJA-ASIA", "SIEA", "SIEA", "SIEJA-JAPAN"]

but when this gets rendered -- they all seem to be duplicates of the first array element?

[image]

---

```
let listRegions = [{
    "label" : "A",
    "value" : "SIEA"
},{
    "label" : "E",
    "value" : "SIEE"
},{
    "label" : "JA",
    "value" : "SIEJA-JAPAN"
},{
    "label" : "AS",
    "value" : "SIEJA-ASIA"
}];


//reg
regions.forEach(function(entry) {

    //const regions6 = ["SIEJA-ASIA", "SIEE"];
    const legendRegions = listRegions.map(region => (
        {
            ...region,
            enabled: entry === region.value
        })
    );
    console.log("legendRegions", legendRegions);

    buildKey(legendRegions)

});


function buildKey(data){

    console.log("DATA", data);


    reg
        .selectAll('.laneKeyText')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.enabled;
        })
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
            if(d.enabled){
                return '#0072ce';
            }
            return '#D8D8D8';
        })
        .attr('x', function(d, i) {
            return (i * 25);
        })
        .attr('dy', 5)
        .attr('dx', 3)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
        .attr('class', 'laneKeyText');

    reg
        .selectAll(".laneKeyRect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr('x', function(d, i) {
            return (i * 25);
        })
        .attr('y', -10)
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("height", 20)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "#D8D8D8")
        .attr('class', 'laneKeyRect');


}
```

Comment: This needs to be a new question. The original question has been properly answered multiple times. Please delete this answer and ask a new question instead.

Comment: Its the same problem -- but implemented -- I can see the data is now correct - but when it goes to render - it errors -- let me raise it as a new question though

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59936414/d3js-error-in-rendering-a-legend-key-duplicated-render