# d3js - error in rendering a legend key - duplicated render?

Tags: d3.js, legend

### I am trying to complete a timeline application - - but I am getting a malfunction with the region key area

[image]

latest fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/fqn4vb90/2/

when this gets rendered -- they all seem to be duplicates of the first array element? So in this example -- first element is JA, the second should be AS, and the third should be E

---

```
let listRegions = [{
    "label" : "A",
    "value" : "SIEA"
},{
    "label" : "E",
    "value" : "SIEE"
},{
    "label" : "JA",
    "value" : "SIEJA-JAPAN"
},{
    "label" : "AS",
    "value" : "SIEJA-ASIA"
}];


//reg
regions.forEach(function(entry) {

    //const regions6 = ["SIEJA-ASIA", "SIEE"];
    const legendRegions = listRegions.map(region => (
        {
            ...region,
            enabled: entry === region.value
        })
    );
    console.log("legendRegions", legendRegions);

    buildKey(legendRegions)

});


function buildKey(data){

    console.log("DATA", data);


    reg
        .selectAll('.laneKeyText')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.label;
        })
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
            if(d.enabled){
                return '#0072ce';
            }
            return '#D8D8D8';
        })
        .attr('x', function(d, i) {
            return (i * 25);
        })
        .attr('dy', 5)
        .attr('dx', 3)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
        .attr('class', 'laneKeyText');

    reg
        .selectAll(".laneKeyRect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr('x', function(d, i) {
            return (i * 25);
        })
        .attr('y', -10)
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("height", 20)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "#D8D8D8")
        .attr('class', 'laneKeyRect');


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is in the following code:

```
...
function buildKey(data){
    reg
    .selectAll('.laneKeyText')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
...
```

Everytime you call `buildKey` inside `foreach` function you are sending the whole data and do a select on all text tags elements, first time text tags are created, but after that they are being selected for data rebind  and then activate the current enabled element, which is different each iteration call, and the current active will be same for all selected text tags in which the all have the same class `.laneKeyText`.

I added here a way to fix it but I'm sure there is a cleaner way to fix it:

https://jsfiddle.net/mamounothman/9fp8oehj/37/

Comment: So you tried to let it render normally - then did a select to re-acquire it to modify that value.

Comment: yes, basically what I did is separate the adding element active color from `select`, `enter`, `append` pattern.

Comment: I resolved it a slightly different way - but you were on the right track. I cleaned up the code with some unique id type methods -- and selected the region block with each legend.